# Trouble with separating a mesh : "Error: Nothing selected"

Tags: mesh, operator

I am new to Blender Scripting and I want to do this :
[image: initial step]
[image: select top building]
[image: separates the top of the building]

I am using Blender v2.80.75 and I have the following code :

[image]

```
selectTopOfBuildingFaces(bm)
for f in bm.faces:
    if f.select == True:
        print("Selection is not empty.")
        break

bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED')
```

My method successfully select the top part of my building as the for loop prints my text

But the console output shows an error :

> *Selection is not empty.*
>
> **Error: Nothing selected**
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\building.blend\building.py",
> line 123, in
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Blender
> Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 201, in
> **call**
> ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
>
> RuntimeError: Error: Nothing selected
>
> Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

I don't understand because I am making sure that faces are selected before calling the operator.

Is it a bug or do you have an example of separating mesh ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: maybe show what you're trying to do with some screenshots and share this part of your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for your input. I added pictures of what I want to do and my whole blender project. I am aware that the code is far from being perfect. Anyway the line that fails is line 123 : bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED')

Comment: You are making your selection on the bmesh not the actual object.

Comment: I do want to separate the top of the Building, but in Python script. What is this Y you are suggesting ?

Comment: If your goal is to select and separate the top part you can do it with Y, is it what you want to do? Actually all your faces are already separated.